# Angularjs validation not working correctly on form

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I have below form:

```
<form name="commentForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" >Enter Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" show-errors>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" ng-model="subject.name" placeholder="Enter Name" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2"  for="comment">Enter comment:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10" show-errors>
            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment" name="comment" ng-model="subject.text" style="resize: none;" required></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group"> 
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button ng-click="submitForm()" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="commentForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I have created showErrors directive to show error for required-fields.

But this form validation is not working properly. Although if I am using the same code in some other partials, it is working fine. What could be the possible mistake that I am making here?

Comment: What is your `show-errors` directive doing. Can you post your `show-errors` directive?

Comment: I checked my controller, and found that there was an error in submitForm which was causing this issue.